When I executes 'npx create-expo-app App3' in order to create a react native project the App.js file won't create
When I executes 'npx create-expo-app App3' in order to create a react native project the App.js file won't create it gives a different template without the App.js file. I've tried manually creating the App.js file and executing it but it doesn't work, I think expo app don't detect it. Below is the image of that template:
File structure of the template creates when I executes 'npx create-expo-app App3'
I executed the 'npx create-expo-app App3' command to get the template of the reactive native project which is for expo-go. But the template doesn't have App.js file.

It is not an error.
Expo has changed its routing system.
Expo now use Expo-router which is a file-base routing. You don't need an index js or app.js file anymore. If you need it :

you can search for the file node_modules/expo-router/index.js
add it as index.js or app.js in the root of your repo.
in package.json change main propecty value to "index.js" or "app.js" according to your filename choice.


Thank you very much, I also checked the expo documentation and understood fully, thank you.

Very glad to be a helpful hand. Please accept the answer if there is nothing left to ask for this problem.
